# JAXB 2.0 Validation not working

Tags: java, xml, validation, jaxb, jaxb2

i am working on JAXB 2.0 and currently struck on the validation part as its not working as expected.
below is the validation code

```
public void validateXMLToSchema(Unmarshaller ummarshaller,String xsdFileName) throws SAXException, JAXBException{
    System.out.println(getClass().getResource(DEFAULT_XSD_NAME).toString());
    Schema schema;
    SchemaFactory schemaFactory=SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    if(null==xsdFileName)
        schema=schemaFactory.newSchema(getClass().getResource(DEFAULT_XSD_NAME));

    else
        schema=schemaFactory.newSchema(new File(xsdFileName));

    ummarshaller.setSchema(schema);
    ummarshaller.setEventHandler( new ValidationEventHandler() {

        @Override
        public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent validationevent) {
            if(validationevent.getSeverity()==ValidationEvent.FATAL_ERROR || validationevent.getSeverity()==ValidationEvent.ERROR || validationevent.getSeverity()==ValidationEvent.WARNING){
                ValidationEventLocator  locator = validationevent.getLocator();
                log.info("Line:Col[" + locator.getLineNumber()
                        + ":" + locator.getColumnNumber()
                        + "]:" + validationevent.getMessage());
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

and here is the call to the method

```
Destination destination=new Destination();
    try {
         destination=(Destination)unmarshal(Destination.class,new FileInputStream(new File("C:/Users/Raisonne/Desktop/jaxb/jaxb-ri-20101119/bin/destination.xml")));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(destination.getName());

}

public static <T> T unmarshal( Class<T> docClass, InputStream inputStream )
throws JAXBException, SAXException {
String packageName = docClass.getPackage().getName();
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( packageName );
Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
XMLValidator xmlValidator=new XMLValidator();
xmlValidator.validateXMLToSchema(u, null);
```

i have few fields as required fields as per XSD but even removing them it shd give me the error while its not giving anything and parsing my xml file in to the corresponding object
can any one point whats going wrong?

here is the part of XSD

```
    <xs:element name="destination" type="Destination"/>
  <xs:complexType name="Destination">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="destinationID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="shortDescription" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="longDescription" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="stateID" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="typeCode" type="xs:int"/>
      <xs:element name="countryCode" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="categories" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="transport" type="Transport" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="culture" type="Culture" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="events" type="Events" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="placesToVisit" type="PlacesToVisit" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="contacts" type="Contact" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="addresses" type="address" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

and the Java file generated

```
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected String name;
protected String destinationID;
protected String shortDescription;
protected String longDescription;
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected String stateID;
```

i was removing stateID from the xml file but still no alarm in validation part

thanks in advance

Comment: Provide the corresponding schema and the JAXB object.

Comment: there are many object created you want only the root object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code fragment is a bit hard to follow, is an unmarshal actually occurring?  You may need to add the last line to your unmarshal method:

```
public static <T> T unmarshal( Class<T> docClass, InputStream inputStream ) throws JAXBException, SAXException {
    String packageName = docClass.getPackage().getName();
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( packageName );
    Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    XMLValidator xmlValidator=new XMLValidator();
    xmlValidator.validateXMLToSchema(u, null);
    u.unmarshal(inputStream);
}
```

Comment: i am unable to pick up what you suggested might be my mind not working :)..can you explian a bit..since i written same thing in my test code and its working fine this mean i am doing some fundamental mistake

Comment: Sure, I don't seem to be able to find where you are calling unmarshal on the Unmarshaller.  I think you may be missing the line "u.unmarshal(inputStream);" in your unmarshal method.  Since unmarshal (on the Unmarshaller) is never being called, no validation events are occuring.

Comment: see my updated answer above..and really sorry since what you have said i am still not able to get it properly if possible can explian with a small code snip so that may be my mind can take it..but honestly this time i am demanding a bit more hope you will not mind

Comment: Finally it came out to be the funny problem the log statement     log.info("Line:Col[" + locator.getLineNumber()
                        + ":" + locator.getColumnNumber()
                        + "]:" + validationevent.getMessage());
it was not working when i changed it to system.out.println it worked   :)     Thanks for the help it saved my day i now i can sleep finally...

Answer (score 0):

According to this line

```
xmlValidator.validateXMLToSchema(u, null);
```

you are not giving the XSD file name to XmlValidator. It should be something like

```
xmlValidator.validateXMLToSchema(u, "/opt/projects/myschema.xsd");
```

Edit: Well this is how I managed to do it and it's working perfectly:

```
void validate(MyRequest requestParameters) throws IllegalArgumentException,MalformedURLException,SAXException {
    try {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyRequest.class.getPackage().getName());
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setSchema(getSchema());
        JAXBElement<MyRequest> rootElement = new JAXBElement<SearchCustomersRequest>(new QName("http://mysite.com/xsd/myproject/", "MyRequest"),
                        MyRequest.class, requestParameters);
        marshaller.marshal(rootElement, new DefaultHandler());
        log.debug("Validation successful");
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid request parameters: " + e.toString(), e);
    }
}

private Schema getSchema() throws MalformedURLException, SAXException {
    if (schema == null) {
        SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(javax.xml.XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        URL schemaUrl = new URL("http://mysite.com/xsd/myproject/schema-1.0.xsd");
        schema = factory.newSchema(schemaUrl);
    }
    return schema;
}
```

Comment: i have handle it in my validateXMLToSchema method if this is null can have look at the code in my post

Comment: Perhaps are namespace issues, I solved that creating a JAXBElement with a defined QName("http://mysite.com/xsd/myproject/"..)

Answer (score 0):

Really strange when i changed my code to this

```
public class UnMarshallXML {

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws SAXException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException {
    Destination destination=new Destination();
    try {
         destination=(Destination)unmarshal(Destination.class,new FileInputStream(new File("C:/Users/Raisonne/Desktop/jaxb/jaxb-ri-20101119/bin/destination.xml")));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(destination.getName());

}

public static <T> T unmarshal( Class<T> docClass, InputStream inputStream )
throws JAXBException, SAXException {
String packageName = docClass.getPackage().getName();
System.out.println(packageName);
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( packageName );
Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
SchemaFactory schemaFactory=SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Schema schema=schemaFactory.newSchema(new File("C:/Users/Raisonne/Desktop/jaxb/jaxb-ri-20101119/bin/destination.xsd"));

u.setSchema(schema);
u.setEventHandler(
        new ValidationEventHandler() {
            // allow unmarshalling to continue even if there are errors
            public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent ve) {
                // ignore warnings
                if (ve.getSeverity() != ValidationEvent.WARNING) {
                    ValidationEventLocator vel = ve.getLocator();
                    System.out.println(
                            "Line:Col[" + vel.getLineNumber()
                            + ":" + vel.getColumnNumber()
                            + "]:" + ve.getMessage());
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
// XMLValidator xmlValidator=new XMLValidator();
//xmlValidator.validateXMLToSchema(u, null,inputStream);
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
JAXBElement<T> doc = (JAXBElement<T>)u.unmarshal( inputStream );
return doc.getValue();
```

}

}

everything started working like charm..

Comment: Like I mentioned in my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399585/jaxb-2-0-validation-not-working/4400111#4400111), you added  the actual unmarshaller.unmarshal call (The second last line in your code).  This causes the XML to be processed an therefore validated.

Comment: i did it same on my validate method but in that case it did not worked out thats why i am wondering i just copied the code from my validation method and placed it inside this ..